# Getting the 5 lowest values with their index from a 2D Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

Any ideas how to get the 5 minimum numbers from a 2D Array. I would like to know their **index** as well. I'm using Processing but I'm interested to find the correct way to do that.

**For example:** I have a 4x4 array with the following values:

```
 3-72-64-4 
 12-45-9-7 
 86-34-81-55 
 31-19-18-21
```

I want to get the five lowest number in my Array which are 3,4,7,9,12. The problem is that I want to know their original index as well.

**Example:**

```
Array[0,0] = 3
Array[0,3] = 4
Array[1,3] = 7
Array[1,2] = 9
```

Is there any formula or good programming way to do that?

Comment: Check out any of the sorting alogrithms. You will get a bunch of answers.

Comment: Sorting will certainly be the easiest way to accomplish this. I suppose if you wan't their original indices, keep a copy of the original 2d-array. And then do a linear search of the 5 min values that you found from your sorted array.

Comment: Since the sort will be O(nlogn) , the linear searches will not affect the runtime [ O(nlogn) + O(5n) = O(nlogn) ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually a very good practice that is suited for your case. It's called the 'merge sort algorithm'. It will sort your values and then you just need to output the first 5 values. Here's a [link specifically for java](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/merge-sort/).  Have fun coding and testing it! I did :D

Comment: Thank you for your post. However I'm trying to sort a 2D array and also know the original index of the sorted numbers.

Comment: Well you can treat each number as a 2 dimension vector (value, index) and sort it by its value.

Answer (score 3):

Well obviously you can just cycle through it and brute force with 2 for loops. Getting the original index makes it harder, as then you cant use sorts, which are faster. If it is sorted or if there is some kind of pattern, you can use a search (binary search) but from what you've given, as it looks as if the data is random, you can't really do much.

If you don't care about indexes, you can try sorts, such as merge sort mentioned by ERed or other types of sorts (I prefer quickSort). Basically you treat the 2D array as a 1D array and assume each subsequent level is just a continuation of the previous level (basically its all just one giant row broken into pieces).